# Can't export babylonjs file from Blender 2.93.4

Tags: javascript, python, 3d, blender, babylonjs

Hi guys i really need your help, so i just installed Blender from Steam because i want the newest Blender software (2.93.4) and i wanna import it to Babylon.js, so, i just want to import simple cube for test like this [cube image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGlfD.png)

as u can see i already downloaded the zip file https://github.com/BabylonJS/BlenderExporter i am using the newest version, also when i trying to import it to babylon file i got this error

```
Exporter version: 2.93.4, Blender version: 2.93.4
========= Conversion from Blender to Babylon.js =========
    Scene settings used :
        Inline textures     :  false
        Material Type       :  PBR
        Positions Precision :  4
        Normals Precision   :  3
        UVs Precision       :  3
        Vert Color Precision:  3
        Mat Weight Precision:  2
        Keep Z-up r-handed  :  no
        Texture directory   :  /home/muhammadfathur/
    Python World class constructor completed
    WARNING: No active camera has been assigned, or is not in a currently enabled collection
    processing begun of mesh:  Cube
        processing begun of material:  Material
========= An error was encountered =========
  File "/home/muhammadfathur/.config/blender/2.93/scripts/addons/babylon_js/json_exporter.py", line 116, in execute
    mesh = Mesh(object, scene, self)
  File "/home/muhammadfathur/.config/blender/2.93/scripts/addons/babylon_js/mesh.py", line 150, in __init__
    recipe = BakingRecipe(bpyMesh, exporter)
  File "/home/muhammadfathur/.config/blender/2.93/scripts/addons/babylon_js/materials/baking_recipe.py", line 43, in __init__
    bjsMaterial = BJSMaterial(bpyMaterial, exporter)
  File "/home/muhammadfathur/.config/blender/2.93/scripts/addons/babylon_js/materials/material.py", line 63, in __init__
    self.textures = {}
ERROR:  readMaterialNodeTree() missing 1 required positional argument: 'overloadChannels'
========= end of processing =========
elapsed time:  0 min, 0.008 secs
```

please help me i really need it thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not what you asked for, but another way to get blender content into babylon is to export to a .glb (GLTF Binary) format.

GLTF is widely supported and will work great in babylon.

I have created a simple starter based on vite (super fast bundler) which contains the minimal code to load a .glb file.

https://github.com/leon/starter-babylonjs

If this is not what you are looking for, maybe someone else will find it useful :)

Comment: is .glb file same as .babylon file? theres should be a reason why babylon team make this importer package

Comment: no .glb is more like a jpeg it's a self contained 3d model with geometry, textures, animations in one file.

a babylon file is a proprietary json which is something the babylon guys came up with long before gltf (glb) files where invented.

you can read more about gltf here
https://www.khronos.org/gltf/

Comment: Thank u soo much u are really awesome